# Send messages from Chrome Extension to External Webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have written a chrome extension that successfully records all of a users scrolling data (timestamp with pixel amount). This data is currently logging in the console.

My next step however is causing me a bit of trouble.

I want to then send every log of data that is created to an external webpage to be displayed. ie, the page will auto update and archive every new timestamped entry/pixel counter the extension records.

I've been able to communicate between the extension and webpage, by passing a simple message through a DOM event. But i'm having trouble getting the extension to send the scroll data it's collecting.

I feel like i'm close, and i've read Google's Messaging API's but I feel a bit lost.

Here's my code so far:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Caressing the Silver Rectangle",
"description": "Measures Jesse Bowling's distance scrolled in pixels on Google Chrome",
"version": "1.1",

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "scroller.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://*/*jessebowling.space/caressingthesilverrectangle/*"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_title": "Caressing the Silver Rectangle",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
]
}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("background.js got a message")
    console.log(request);
    console.log(sender);
    sendResponse("bar");
}
);
```

**Scroller.js**

```
/*jslint devel: true */

// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var caressingthesilverrectangleId = 
"http://*/*jessebowling.space/caressingthesilverrectangle/*"
var totalScroll;
var lastKnownScrollPos = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
"use strict";
console.log(lastKnownScrollPos);
totalScroll += Math.abs(window.scrollY - lastKnownScrollPos);
lastKnownScrollPos = window.scrollY;
chrome.storage.sync({ scroll: totalScroll });
function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
});


// send data through a DOM event
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('csEvent', {detail: 
totalScroll}));


// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(caressingthesilverrectangleId, 
{getTargetData: true},
function(response) {
if (targetInRange(response.targetData))
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(caressingthesilverrectangleId, 
{activateLasers: true});
 });

// Start a long-running conversation:
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(caressingthesilverrectangleId);
port.postMessage(chrome.storage.sync({ scroll: totalScroll }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the part where you do

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(caressingthesilverrectangleId);
port.postMessage(chrome.storage.sync({
    scroll: totalScroll
}));
```

is where you are trying to send the message. However the message you are sending is the result of chrome.storage.sync, which is always `undefined`. You might want to split these two calls up so you actually send some data like:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(caressingthesilverrectangleId);        
chrome.storage.sync({
    scroll: totalScroll
});
port.postMessage({
    scroll: totalScroll
});
```